# How can I enum RT_VERSION resource languages?

Tags: windows, delphi

I am currently trying to enum all resource languages from the `RT_VERSION` resourcetype.
This is what I have so far with no luck, since my callback procedure doesn't fire at all.

```
function TEnumResLangProc (hModule: HMODULE; lpszType, lpszName : PChar; wIDLanguage : Word; lParam : Longint) : Bool; stdcall;
begin
  MessageBox(0, lpszName, '', 0); // For testing
  MessageBox(0, lpszType, '', 0); // For testing
  result := true;
end;

if not EnumResourceLanguages (HINSTANCE, RT_VERSION, PChar('1'), @TEnumResLangProc, 0)
then RaiseLastOSError;
```

I always get the errorcode 1813 and I couldn't find any documentation about it. I'm also not sure about the "Index" Paramater `PChar('1')` What do I do wrong and how can I enum all `RT_VERSION` languages?

Edit:

The value 1031 is wanted

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error code is `ERROR_RESOURCE_TYPE_NOT_FOUND`. It means that there are no resources of that type and name in the specified module.

> The specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.

Note that the error codes are documented: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381.aspx

Quite likely the name is wrong. Did you mean to pass `MakeIntResource(1)` or `'#1'`?

Your callback function should set the return value. The compiler will warn you of that mistake. You really should enable and heed warnings. Also, the type declarations are not 64 bit compatible, but I doubt that matters here.

Comment: @Sertac FWIW, I wonder why you prefer `PChar` to `MakeIntResource`

Comment: It is an alias for PChar, but in fact I prefer Pointer. It is shorter, more to the point. :)

Comment: @Sertac, methinks its quite safe to truncate resource name to `Word` if `IS_INTRESOURCE` returns true.

Comment: @Free - It is. That is the whole point of IS_INTRESOURCE, no pointers in the first 64kb. Oh, you mean the deleted answer. You're right, I didn't pay attention.